# See saved class from NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I wonder if it's possible to somehow see to saved `NSManagedObject` classes from a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification?

I have tried something like this:

```
[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey] [???]
```

I want to check if the first object in this dictionary is. `[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey]` returns something like this:

```
$0 = 0x0a4c2bd0 {(
    <StreamType: 0x94d5910> (entity: StreamType; id: 0xa4c86d0 <x-coredata://B9DA2DE0- 26E0-4BA1-A0A1-14E4EC54E24F/StreamType/p1> ; data: {
    posts =  ...
```

So, I want to check if the first object kind of class `StreamType`. But I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: So the question is actually about knowing what type of class something is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey]` returns an `NSSet`, which is an *unordered* collection and does not have a "first element".

You can test all inserted object by enumerating the set:

```
NSSet *inserted = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
for (NSManagedObject *obj in inserted) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[StreamType class]]) { 
        ...
    }
}
```